# Transfer data | Django Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, web-deployment, heroku-cli

How to transfer data from the local database to the production database for a **Django** app deployed in **Heroku**.

I've just deployed my project, but after the migration, the models were empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate fixtures of your local database tables and then load them in your production database.

You can do this all with django commands: dumpdata and loaddata.

You can read the docs on how to do it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/). With it you can load and dump data
from the database into files that are called fixtures. Django supports fixtures in JSON,XML, or YAML formats.

Here is an example for `json` format. Suppose you have a `app` name `courses` in your Django project. Then make a `fixtures` folder inside `courses` app. After that can dump data with the following command inside `courses/fixtures/`.

```
python manage.py dumpdata courses --indent=2 --output=courses/fixtures/
file_name.json
```

Then you can load back data into database with `loaddata`.

```
python manage.py loaddata file_name.json
```

And to simply test, you can also dump data on `terminal` with the following command.

```
python manage.py dumpdata courses --indent=2
```